# extjs form trigger store

Tags: forms, store, extjs

When i write  `myForm.getForm().updateRecord(this.record);` it triggers the store to call ***update*** function.
the form tirggers the ***update*** function, I do not trigger it directly.

How do i trigger ***add*** function when a new record is added via the form (i mean, what do i need to write in the form in order to trigger ***add*** (create) function of the store. I don't want to call the store.add function directly, i want the form to call it) ?

How do i trigger ***read***(by id) function in store via the form ?

some more clarification:
in the form, there is an "Apply" button with a handler.
when the button is pressed i am preforming `store.add(<--new_record-->)` .
but, i don't want to call the store function directly, i want to use the form to call this function.
How do i do that ?

Thx

Comment: do you want to trigger the **add** and **read** events when the **update** event is fired?

Comment: Jaitsu, i've edited my answer.  i want to trigger add when a new record is created in the form

Comment: can you post the code for your form on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Jaitsu, i've edited again my answer. sorry, but i am not able to post my code.